Resource object filter is returning prefix without file
I have this issue, but don't know why is happening:
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prefix/a/'):
    print(obj)

s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='prefix/a/')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='prefix/a/file1.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='prefix/a/file2.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='prefix/a/file3.csv')

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='prefix/b/'):
    print(obj)

s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='prefix/b/file4.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='prefix/b/file5.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='prefix/b/file6.csv')

Why I'm getting an object without files in the first case?

The first case is showing 4 objects.  prefix/a/' is a valid object name.  No doubt it's a zero byte object that was created when some user created a "Folder" in the AWS web console.

there's no such an object, both "paths" holds just files inside

How are you determining there's no such object?

There's nothing listed when I access the path, just the files

How are you accessing the path?  The Website?  The AWS CLI?  Some other method?

Through boto3 package and also AWS console.

The AWS Management Console will hide any objects that end in a / as it presents fake folders.  Boto3 doesn't do that.

ANy idea on how to delete that object terminated in /?

Pretty much like any other object, with something like aws s3 rm s3://example-bucket/object/that/ends/with/slash/
